# Sencha - combining dataview with button in same view

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am very new to Sencha and I am trying to get a button under a DataView in a Panel. I have tried different scenario's.

**The View**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Profile', {
extend : 'Ext.Panel',
xtype : 'profileview',

requires : ['MyApp.store.UserStore', 'Ext.List', 'Ext.DataView', 'Ext.data.Store'],

initialize : function() {
    var me = this;
    var record = 1;
    //Create the instance of the store and load it
    var userStore = Ext.create('MyApp.store.UserStore');
    userStore.load();

    //Create the dataview
    var view = Ext.create('Ext.DataView', {
        store : userStore,
        itemTpl : ['<h1>Mijn Profiel</h1>', '<h2>{USERNAME}</h2>', '<p>{EMAIL}</p><br/>', '<img src="http://www.MyApp.nl/{AVATAR_PATH}" />', '<br/>'].join()
    });
    //Add the dataview to the panel
    me.add(view);

    /**
     var button = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
     text : 'Edit',
     handler : function() {
     Ext.Msg.alert('You clicked the button');
     }
     });
     */
    //me.add(button);

},

config : {
    title : 'Profiel',
    iconCls : 'user3',
    scrollable : true,
    styleHtmlContent : true,
    items : [{
        xtype : 'button',
        text : 'Edit',
        handler : function() {
            Ext.Msg.alert('You clicked the button');
        }
    }]
}
});
```

The above view shows only the button but NOT the Dataview. I needed to add

```
layout : 'fit'
```

to the config to make it show DataView. But in combination with the button it makes the button fullscreen and the dataview is not shown anymore (???).

I tried both scenario's where I add a Button as config item and by using the handler.

How can I get the button below the dataview ??

Thanks for your help.

Comment: try giving bottom: '10px' to button and let me know

Comment: that did not work, so I added a height property to the button, now i see but the button is on top and overlaying the dataview (??)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use layout fit, it's made to fit one component in your canvas. I'd use a vbox layout. Which automatically puts items vetically under each other.

Try this:

```
layout: {
   type: 'vbox',
   align: 'stretch' //this tells to take the full width
}
```

Flex your dataview

```
var view = Ext.create('Ext.DataView', {
    flex: 1, //Use the remaining space.
    store : userStore,
    itemTpl : ['<h1>Mijn Profiel</h1>', '<h2>{USERNAME}</h2>', '<p>{EMAIL}</p><br/>', '<img src="http://www.MyApp.nl/{AVATAR_PATH}" />', '<br/>'].join()
});
```

Comment: hi Johan, this indeed shows the dataview, but now it is below the button. How can I show the edit button below the dataview ?

Comment: You'll have to use `insert` instead of `add`. So: `me.insert(0, view);`   http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.Panel-method-insert